# Воспроизведение звука с трансляции SHOUTcast радио

Tags: java, android, аудио

Хочу воспроизвести звук на ***Android 2.3***, с трансляции радио ***SHOUTcast***, без всяких примочек, 1-ним кликом на кнопку. Все попытки тщетны. Возможно, еще нужна какая нибудь специальная библиотека кодеков? Поделитесь любым советом, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

mp.setDataSource("http://ссылка на радио");
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Можно все это дело обернуть в `service` и играть в фоне.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    String url = "http://..."; // Твой URL
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
    mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Не забудь пермишн для интернета взять.